# Db::getInstance()->insert() shows no error, doesn't work

Tags: prestashop

I am inserting data into database. It doesn't get inserted. If I do the same via raw SQL it works. Doesn't show any errors too.

```
 $products = Context::getContext()->cart->getProducts();
 foreach($products as $product){
      $id_product = $product['id_product'];
      $is_allowed = (bool) Db::getInstance()->execute("SELECT available_for_order FROM ps_product WHERE id_product=".$id_product); // is product availabe for order when stock is null or zero. 

      // $sql = 'INSERT INTO `cart_log` (`id_product`,`ids_product_attribute`,`stock`,`reference`,`available_for_order`,`created_at`)
      // VALUES (' . $id_product. ', ' . $product['id_product_attribute'] . ',' . $product['stock_quantity'] . ', ' . $product['reference'] .','. $is_allowed .', NOW())';
      // die($sql);
      $data= array(
           'id_product' => (string) $id_product,
           'ids_product_attribute' =>(string) $product['id_product_attribute'],
           'stock' =>(string) $product['stock_quantity'],
           'reference' =>(string) $product['reference'],
           'available_for_order' =>(int) $is_allowed,
           'created_at' => 'NOW())'
      );
      echo "<pre>";
      print_r($data);
      echo "</pre>";

      $result= Db::getInstance()->insert('cart_log',$data);
 }
```

Comment: can you add the ``cart_log`` table definition please ?

Comment: whats the type of your column ``created_at`` ? you are passing a string ``'NOW())`` instead of a date in the array $data

Answer (score 0):

try replace :

```
$is_allowed = (bool) Db::getInstance()->execute("SELECT available_for_order FROM ps_product WHERE id_product=".$id_product); // is product availabe for order when stock is null or zero.
```

by

```
$is_allowed = (bool) Db::getInstance()->getValue("SELECT available_for_order FROM ps_product WHERE id_product=".$id_product); // is product availabe for order when stock is null or zero.
```

`execute()` will return `true` or `false` if the request has correctly been executed, but not the request result. `getValue()` **will** return you request result.

There is also `getRow()` to get multiple elements of a same line, and `executeS()` to get multiple lines.

Regards